# Jquery Mobile Page trasition displaying Extra elements

Tags: android, ios, mobile, jquery-mobile

http://kzoomarketing.com/hapman/#main

This is a link to an app that I have been working on.  The issue is that the page transitions display an unstyled menu that is in the footer of a few pages.

I cannot for the life me figure out where in the code this is coming from.

If any one can view the source and help me I would appreciate it.

Comment: I get a 404 for this: http://kzoomarketing.com/hapman/jquery.scrollto.js so scrolling is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On line, 
1363 in your code..

```
<div id="reloadBtn" width="100%"><img style="margin-left:49%; margin-top: 1%;
   cursor: pointer;" "id="reloadSavedFlowcharts" src="images/blue/reload_24x28.png" 
   onClick="synchFlowcharts()"></div>
```

You have put wrong additional **`"`** before **id=**.

Correct one:

```
<div id="reloadBtn" width="100%"><img style="margin-left:49%; margin-top: 1%;
   cursor: pointer;" id="reloadSavedFlowcharts" src="images/blue/reload_24x28.png" 
   onClick="synchFlowcharts()"></div>
```